# How can I retrieve all the returned variables from a function?

Tags: python, variables, random

```
import random

def some_function():
    example = random.randint(0, 1)
    if example == 1:
        other_example = 2
    else:
        return False
    return example, other_example
```

With this example, there is a chance that either one or two variables will be returned. Usually, for one variable I'd use  `var = some_function()` while for two, `var, var2 = some_function()`. How can I tell how many variables are being returned by the function?

Answer (score 2):

try something like this:

```
>>> lis=(1,)[:2] #just one value, 
>>> lis
(1,)


>>> lis=(1,2)[:2]   #two values
>>> lis
(1, 2)


>>> lis=(1,2,3,4,5)[:2]  #any number of values
>>> lis
(1, 2)

# used [:2] here, because you only expect a maximum of 2 values
# use [:] to collect any number of values
```

But the only problem with this approach is that you need to return a `tuple` at every `return` statement,
so `return False` becomes `return False,`

using `iter()`, this too expect that you always return a tuple or any iterable:

```
>>> ret=((1,))
>>> ret=iter((1,))
>>> a,b=ret.next(),list(ret)[:1]  #used [:1] coz we need to store only 2 elements
>>> a,b
(1, [])


>>> ret=iter((1,2))
>>> a,b=ret.next(),list(ret)[:1]
>>> a,b
(1, [2])

>>> ret=iter((1,2,3,4))
>>> a,b=ret.next(),list(ret)[:1]
>>> a,b
(1, [2])
```

Answer (score 2):

There's no guaranteed way to tell the difference between a function that returns a single `tuple` and one that returns multiple non-tuple values. If you know that the function doesn't return a `tuple`, though, then you can use this code to check for multiple return values:

```
return_val = some_function()
if isinstance(return_val, tuple):
    # number of returned values is len(return_val)
    if len(return_val) == 2:
        var, var2 = return_val
else:
    # returned a single non-tuple item
    var = return_val
```

The best way to handle this, however, is to write functions that don't return different numbers of values in different cases. Instead, you can do something like...

```
def some_function():
    example = random.randint(0, 1)
    if example == 1:
        other_example = 2
    else:
        return False, None
    return example, other_example
```

...so that the function always returns two values. Alternatively, you can always return a single tuple, and just check for the number of elements in that tuple (so for instance, returning an empty tuple `()` or a tuple with a single false value `(False,)`.

Answer (score 1):

```
var_returned = some_function()
num_vars = len(vars_returned) if (not vars_returned == False) else 0
```

ternary then! this can be done even shorter.

```
vars_returned = 7, 2
num_vars = len(vars_returned) if vars_returned else 0
print(num_vars)
# 2

vars_returned = False
num_vars = len(vars_returned) if vars_returned else 0
print(num_vars)
# 0
```

Comment: This will fail for single return values (e.g. `TypeError: 'bool' object is not iterable`), if the returned value is not an iterable (and will give the wrong answer if it's an iterable with length greater than 1).

Answer (score 1):

Why not try this:

```
import random

def some_function():
    example = random.randint(0, 1)
    if example == 1:
        other_example = 2
    else:
        return ()
    return example, other_example
```

This way you will always have a tuple as return value, but the tuple will test as False when you want it to. Use it like this:

```
answer = some_function()
if answer:
     var1, var2 = answer
```

Answer (score 1):

It's bad practice to have a function returning significantly different types. Typically if a function returns tuples, it will always return tuples and they'll always have the same number of items, except in cases where they return `None`. The reason is exactly what prompted you to ask this question: it's difficult to interpret a given return value. And everywhere you call your function, you'll have the overhead of decoding the return value. And any documentation would have to explain what output to expect in each case.

There are quite a few reasonable alternatives. You could return objects that wrap your data in some context, or a dictionary, or a [collections.namedtuple](http://docs.python.org/library/collections.html#collections.namedtuple). Or, for most real-world code, you could carve it into functions along different lines that are easier to understand.